# Position of window titeles in Xubuntu/Compiz 12.04

Tags: compiz, xubuntu

How can I set up window titles in the left corner?

I am using gconf-editor to change themes, fonts etc whilst using compiz but I couldnt find this option.

Comment: This depends on which window decorator you are using. If it is the gtk-decorator, it will consume the metacity settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have to resolve this issue by:

1. Open `dconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` -> `button-layout`
3. Put follow value there: `close,maximize,minimize:menu` and hit enter

That's all!